# (Re)Create table from "backup" table description

Tags: python, django, postgresql

### Issue

Recently I came across an issue with a client, that has many solutions, but none was easy. This application uses Postgresql DB and there are two environments: `dev` and `prod`.

At some point someone thought that it was a good idea to delete one of the tables (`module_people_new`) from `prod` without taking care of the FK and other issues that it could carry. Luckily, it was a module that was not very coupled with the application so the application kept working just fine.

When I started working with this application, some functions were failing with integrity errors, so I found out it was because of that. I tried the same functions in `dev` and saw that they were working, so the table was there.

### Postgresql table description

Now, I was wondering if there is a way to "recover" that table in `prod`, from the information I have in `dev`. I know that I could just get the table description and built a create query from there, but I was wondering if there is a more "direct" way. With table description I mean:

```
db-> \d+ module_people_new
                               Table "public.module_people_new"
          Column           |           Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                        | integer                  | not null  | plain    |              |
 created_at                | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
 updated_at                | timestamp with time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
 first_name                | character varying(255)   | not null  | extended |              |
 last_name                 | character varying(255)   | not null  | extended |              |
 user_id                   | integer                  | not null  | plain    |              |
 . . .
Indexes:
    "module_people_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    . . .
Check constraints:
    . . .
Foreign-key constraints:
    "module_user_id_4d9d48da00e81837_fk_module_user_id" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES module_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    . . .
```

### Another possibility

The application is a Django app, so I also have the migrations, but I'm afraid there have been a few changes that may have affected that table and others related. But, maybe I could use that. The only problem is that I don't want to copy-paste the migration and simply apply it, cross-finger and hope it works. I know that you can get the SQL query from Django ORM queries, maybe there is a way to get the query from a migration as well?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ruddra's answer, I ended up doing this:

1. Copy model People to a new model.
2. Remove `related_names` (there were some in this model) and remove `db_table` (that's why the table had a `_new` in the end)
3. Generate migration: `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. Apply migration: `python manage.py migrate`
5. Rename new model table to missing People table name (`_id_seq` table too)
6. Apply fake migration to go back to the state previous to the new model migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake app_name 0XXX_..._...
```

7. Remove new model and migration

And that was it!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility I could think of is to use [inspectdb](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) to inspect the table in dev and output it in a model.

```
python manage.py inspectdb module_people_new > models.py
```

Then generate migrations and create the tables in the production. Then you can create a script to re-populate the table like this:

```
# some_script.py

from some_app.models import User

# assuming `module_people_new` table's Model Name is ModulePeople

for user in User.objects.all():
   ModulePeople.objects.get_or_create(user=user, first_name=user.first_name, ...)
```

Then use that script like this:

```
python manage.py shell < some_script.py
```

Or if you want to populate data from database directly from dev, then you can use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/initial-data/#where-django-finds-fixture-files). You can [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) from dev and use [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) in production.

Comment: Well, I do have the model itself in the code. The problem is that whoever deleted it, simply did a `DROP TABLE` and did not remove it from the code. So if I try to `makemigrations`, it will not find any changes. Anyway, I ran `inspectdb` and it gave me a clue about whether the current model in the code was the same as the one in the `dev` database. I will take a look about the fixtures, dumpdata and loaddata. Thanks!

Comment: You can try something like this: Comment out the model code, then run **makemigrations** and **migrate** in production. Then un-comment the code, and run makemigrations and migrate again. But before doing these, please back up your db.

Comment: Yes, based on your answer I ended up doing something like that. I'll post an answer with the steps. Thanks a lot!